# Multiple "ors" and "ands" in a if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, web

I just have a question about my code below. The if statements are not working correctly, they are not testing months correctly. I beleive where the problem is is in the not equal to parts. Using the script this is where the problem seems to be arisig. I am not 100% familar to the javascript syntax in this regard. Thanks

```
<script = text/javascript>          
            function calculate(){
            var year = parseInt(document.getElementById("year").value);
            var month = parseInt(document.getElementById("month").value);
            var day = parseInt(document.getElementById("day").value);

            if ((month == 2 && day > 28) && (!(year == 2016) || (!(year == 2020))) && day > 28)
            {
                alert("Sorry. The day " + day + " is not available in the month of February in the year of " + year);
            }
            else if((month == 2 && day > 29) && ((year == 2016) || (year == 2020))){
                alert("Sorry. The day " + day + " is not available in the month of February in the year of " + year);
            }
            else
            {

            newmonth = month + 9;
            newday = day + 10;

            //if the month is greater then 12 roll over the year and change the month
            if ((newmonth > 12)){
                year = year + 1;
                newmonth = newmonth - 12;
            }
            //if the day equals January and has a day grater than 31 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 31) && (newmonth == 1)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 31;
            }
            //if the day equals February and has a day grater than 28 on a non leap year then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 28) && (newmonth == 2) && (year == 2014)){
                    newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                    newday = newday - 28;
            }
            //if the day equals February and has a day grater than 29 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 29) && (newmonth == 2) && (year == 2016)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 29;
            }
            //if the day equals February and has a day grater than 29 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 29) && (newmonth == 2) && (year == 2020)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 29;
            }
            //if the day equals February and has a day grater than 29 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 29) && (newmonth == 2) && (year == 2024)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 29;
            }
            //if the day equals February and has a day grater than 29 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 29) && (newmonth == 2) && (year == 2028)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 29;
            }
            //if the day equals March and has a day grater than 31 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 31) && (newmonth == 3)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 31;
            }
            //if the day equals April and has a day grater than 30 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 30) && (newmonth == 4)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 30;
            }
            //if the day equals May and has a day grater than 31 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 31) && (newmonth == 5)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 31;
            }
            //if the day equals June and has a day grater than 30 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 30) && (newmonth == 6)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 30;
            }               
            //if the day equals July and has a day grater than 31 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 31) && (newmonth == 7)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 31;
            }
            //if the day equals March and has a day grater than 31 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 31) && (newmonth == 8)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 31;
            }
            //if the day equals September and has a day grater than 30 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 30) && (newmonth == 9)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 30;
            }
            //if the day equals October and has a day grater than 31 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 31) && (newmonth == 10)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 31;
            }
            //if the day equals November and has a day grater than 30 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 30) && (newmonth == 11)){
                newmonth = newmonth + 1;
                newday = newday - 30;
            }
            //if the day equals December and has a day grater than 31 then roll over to the next month
            if ((newday > 31) && (newmonth == 12)){
                newmonth = 1;
                newday = newday - 31;
            }
            alert("Your cow is due to calve on:"+" Day "+newday+" Month "+newmonth+" Year "+year);              
            }
            }
```

Comment: 99% of times where I blamed an `if` for my code not working right, it turned out to be my fault. Just saying :)

Comment: JavaScript has a `Date` object.  You should use it instead of writing so much code.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(!(year == 2016) || (!(year == 2020)))
```

Will be true for any value of year, you probably want

```
(!((year == 2016) || (year == 2020)))
```

Also you check that `day > 28` twice.